# how to run multiple commands in linux terminal

Tags: angularjs, node.js, linux, npm, command-line-interface

I am using **Ubuntu 16.04** and working on project in **angularJs** and **node.js** where i have to open 7 terminals and type **npm start** in each terminal to run the project.

Is there any easy way to run the project?

Comment: please first answer the question and then downvote if you like.

Comment: Not sure what your comment is referring to, and why you're telling people to downvote your question (or that they must first answer you). As it stands, it's not really looking like a programming question. If it's about ubuntu and working with the shell, you can post your question to askubuntu.com. But, as written, there's no programming question here. We don't even know about your specific development environment. So, as written, this question is unclear (and not a programming question).  And people will choose to upvote, downvote, or answer, independent of specific demands.

Comment: @DavidMakogon can you suggest a platform where i can ask questions like how to install something or how to do technical work in easy way. Because Stackoverflow is not for this type of questions.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need 7 terminals for angularJS and NodeJS project, but possible options to ease the pain :

1. Use tmux for linux which basically lets you break one terminal window into several windows so that you can manage run different commands in each part without multiple terminals in your launcher.
2. Use npm scripts in package.json file which is much better option.

package.json file

```
{
...
"scripts": {
               "many": "concurrently \"command1\" \"command2\""
           }
"devDependencies": {
                       "concurrently": "3.5.1" //or any version you want
                   }
...
}
```

run the script as "npm run many" in the terminal.
you can make the command list as complex as you want or further break it down.

Hopefully that solves your specific problem.

Answer (score -1):

using an advanced ide like intelij or webstorm might help you even thought it's not an answer to your question